# High Chart Generate black blank in Visual force

Tags: visualforce, highcharts

I just copy paste the demo from HighChart to my Developer Edition platform below.Refer to [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/2xYSm/) for High chart demo.

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" >
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.HighChart_5,'/api/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js')}"/>
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.HighChart_5,'/code/js/highcharts.js')}"/>
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.HighChart_5,'/code/js/highcharts-more.js')}"/>
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.HighChart_5,'/code/js/modules/exporting.js')}"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
  var chart;
  $(document).ready(function() {
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Browser market shares at a specific website, 2010'
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage}%</b>',
            percentageDecimals: 1
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    color: '#000000',
                    connectorColor: '#000000',
                    formatter: function() {
                        return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ this.percentage +' %';
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Browser share',
            data: [
                ['Firefox',   45.0],
                ['IE',       26.8],
                {
                    name: 'Chrome',
                    y: 12.8,
                    sliced: true,
                    selected: true
                },
                ['Safari',    8.5],
                ['Opera',     6.2],
                ['Others',   0.7]
            ]
        }]
    });
});

});
</script>

</head>


<body>

<div id="container" style="width:600px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

</body>
</html>
</apex:page>
```

The issue is it generated black blank container without any chart.I check Developer console and there is no javascript error except for this:

> Unrecognized Content-Security-Policy directive 'reflected-xss'.
> Unrecognized Content-Security-Policy directive 'referrer'.

What step that I missed?

Comment: did you uncheck the Enable XSS protection in session settings?

Comment: Yes, XSS Protection is uncheck.

Comment: i checked same code with high chart CDNs, though i get the same console error but I'm getting the chart properly.

Comment: @blackPerlSAF you using the same demo code?

Comment: yes i used same code. but i used CDNs others than static resource.

Comment: Is it due to that? How can I be sure?Would you mine to copy paste how you call the library?Maybe I can try.

Comment: I'm not sure that it is happening because of that, but your highchart code looks fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57284/discussion-between-unidha-and-blackperl-saf).

Comment: No need to add both `$(function () {` and `$(document).ready(function() {` only one is fine both are the same. You should remove one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used your demo code and downloaded the highchart files from the link which you had given in the chat room. and i got the error saying that highchart is not defined in console. when I checked my downloaded file there was two highcharts.js files. one is inside code folder and one more is inside js folder. And js folder was inside code folder. so if we use /code/js/highcharts.js we get the error sayiong highcharts not defined though i can see the highcharts.js file in source. So I tried using  highcharts.js which is present in code it is working fine. here is those lines.

```
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.HighChart_5,'/code/highcharts.js')}"/> 
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.HighChart_5,'/code/js/modules/exporting.js')}"/> 
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.HighChart_5,'/api/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js')}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually this issue caused by Highchart 5.0.10 . We called library from CDN it works well, same goes with older version also it works.

The error on Content Security Policy still appear but it is not the reason why the chart is blank.

Comment: i faced the same problem and i solved it by using <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.HighChart_5,'/code/highcharts.js')}"/> 
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.HighChart_5,'/code/js/modules/exporting.js')}"/> 
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.HighChart_5,'/api/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js')}"/>

Comment: it seem similar with the code in question but not working for me.

Comment: no it is not similar '/code/highcharts/'. in demo it is /code/js/highcharts

Comment: just try and check

Comment: i use the code same like above not working.